# CMake not linking OpenSSL

Tags: c, cmake

I am currently making a static library that will be using OpenSSL. When CMake is generating the MakeFiles the OpenSSL libraries is not linked in it so the compilation fails with error:

```
iot.c:(.text+0x3f5): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
iot.c:(.text+0x41c): undefined reference to `HMAC'
```

I first thought it could be that The CMake instruction should go in CMakeLists.txt that should go in the iotlib/CMakeLists.txt but then I'll get errors when generating the MakeFiles.

The main file is just for example use of the iotlib and for testing while all code for the library is in iotlib-files.

The code for my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(iotcloud_lib)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules/")

enable_testing()

# Includes for checkers
include(cppcheck.cmake) # TODO: Move to a module

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

# Set compiler flags
set (warnings "-Wall -Wextra -Werror")

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
add_subdirectory(iotlib)
add_subdirectory(tests)

add_executable(iotcloud ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(iotcloud ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(iotcloud iotlib)
```

---

And the line in my iotlib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library (iotlib STATIC iot.c)
```

This is how my I decided to have my folder structure look like.

```
+-- bin
+-- build
|   +-- MakeFile
|   +-- iotlib
|       +-- MakeFile
+-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- CMakeModules
|   +-- FindCheck.cmake
|   +-- FindOpenSSL.cmake
|   +-- FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake
|   +-- FindPackageMessage.cmake
+-- cppcheck.cmake
+-- iotlib
|   +-- algo.h
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
|   +-- iot.c
|   +-- iot_error.h
|   +-- iot.h
+-- main.c
+-- tests
```

Comment: Order matters! If library A depends on library B then A *must* come *before* B. Try changing the order of the `target_link_libraries` commands.

Comment: Tried to change order of the `target_link_libraries`. Same error.

Comment: After have been working on this problem for some hours I now found it, The problem was in another CMakeList... The CMakeList that handles my test cases. Apparently the testcases is compiled on the same time as my normal library.